# Class type object as HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create an action that would look like `controller/action?param1=val&param2=val` with the `HttpGet` annotation.

What I have is:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index(SomeClass obj)
{
    // do stuff
    return View(something);
}
```

I can access the action via `controller/Index?obj.param1=val&obj.param2=val`, but is there a way to avoid `obj.param1` and `obj.param2` in the query string and have something like `controller/Index?page=val&amount=val`.

Putting those parameters in the annotation like this didn't work: `[HttpGet("/page={obj.subobject.param1}&amount={obj.subobject.param2}")]`

Comment: You mean like routing, so `controller/action/val1/val2`? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you actually want to post "obj" ? If you really need it, AND if POST method is not an option, I there's no solution... The best you can do is probably to shorten the actual route to reach the page.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have updated the submission with what I have tried.

Comment: What about simply taking the individual parameters, to your method, then constructing the object inside? What is the problem you're trying to solve here, that the url "looks funky"?

Comment: @AFract I am trying to get it as a GET value (through query strings).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, the URL would looks quite weird the way it is now, so I want to avoid it.

Comment: So how about just `Index(int page, int amount)` instead then?

Comment: There's some other data in the SomeClass instance that's important to keep, so that's why I didn't go that way. Although, that would've worked, but I want to keep the two parameters in an instance.

Comment: If the url is only going to provide 2 values, what is the difference?

Comment: You could use the [Route] attribute above your action and specify the template (e.g `[Route("page={obj.subobject.param1}&amount={obj.subobject.param2}")]`). That should help the application recognize the URL parameters as your `subobject`fields.

Comment: @TheDoomDestroyer I don't think ASP.NET is able to parse query parameters into an object, using only a routing template. If it should work you should probably use `HttpGet` over `Route` nonetheless.

Comment: @TobiasTengler Oddly enough, I just checked it and it seems to work properly on my end.

Comment: What is the class for `SomeClass ` and what is your .net core version? As the suggestion from poke, for asp.net core, it should work with `?foo=baz&bar=qux`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the default model binding setup, you can just pass the parameter names directly and ASP.NET Core will automatically put the values into the `SomeClass` object:

```
public IActionResult Test(SomeClass obj)
{
    return Json(obj);
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

When opening the URL `/Home/Test?foo=baz&bar=qux` you will now see that the object is properly filled with the `Foo` and `Bar` properties.